# Application hangs when calling external constructor -- troubleshooting steps?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, avalonedit

This may be a long shot but I'm out of ideas.

I've got a VS C# solution with three projects in it. There's a class library project and then two application projects that depend on that class library. The class library in turn depends on a few other DLLs including the avalonedit dll from the sharpdevelop project.

One of the applications is building and running fine, including a use of my own control that wraps the avalonedit control. The other application is failing to run and it seems to be failing at the point when the avalonedit control is initialised via the XAML in my wrapping control.

The problem is that I don't see any errors in the debug output at all, all I see is the dll loaded message and then nothing. If I step into the constructor of my control the step never completes. The debugger says the app is running, but it is apparently spinning somewhere in the avalonedit dll when the underlying edit control is constructed by the XAML side.

I have to assume that there's some issue with difference in environment between the two projects but I'm kind of stumped as to how to proceed in tracking the problem down. Am I going to have to somehow get arrange matters so that I can put a break in the avalonedit source?

Edit: If I pause/break all it just drops back to the line calling my control constructor.

Comment: What happens if you pause the debugger during the hang?

Comment: This is where [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) comes in handy!

Comment: I will suggest picking source (and/or PDB) of AvalonEdit and then hitting pause in debugger to see the issue. Another approach would be to inspect avalonedit constructor source using Reflector (as Mayank suggested) to see potential cause of loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a deadlock. Take a close look at all threads, their stack traces and synchronization primitives (locks, semaphores, etc.). Keep in mind: contended resources may not be explicit (for example, when you are inside static constructor waiting on something that tries to get access to a static field of the type being constructed you get a deadlock).

There are many ways to introduce a deadlock but no simple advice to handle it. You could also enable break on all exceptions in Visual Studio (Debug -> Exceptions... and tick CLR Exceptions).

If this does not help you could provide stack traces here and maybe somebody could spot the problem.